# Transparent view

Tags: tornadofx

I would like to create a View (stage, window) with partially transparent background. I have an image containing alpha channel

[image: an image containing alpha channel]

I used this kind of scenes in JavaFx, where I had to set the scene fill to null and the root node background color to transparent. I tried the same with TornadoFX:

```
class NextRoundView : View("Következő kör") {

    override val root = vbox {
        style {
            backgroundColor = multi(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            backgroundImage = multi(URI.create("/common/rope-bg-500x300.png"))
            backgroundRepeat = multi(BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT 
                                  to BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT)
        }
        prefWidth = 500.0
        prefHeight = 300.0

        spacing = 20.0
        padding = insets(50, 20)
        text("A text") {
            font = Font.font(40.0)
            alignment = Pos.CENTER
        }

        button("OK")
        {
            font = Font.font(20.0)
            action {
                close()
            }
        }
        sceneProperty().addListener{ _,_,n ->
            n.fill = null
        }
    }

}
```

I'm calling the view like this:

```
NextRoundView().apply { 
    openModal(stageStyle = StageStyle.TRANSPARENT, block = true) 
}
```

However, the stage is still has background:

[image]

What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made a couple of mistakes that causes this. First of all, you must never manually instantiate UICompoenents (View, Fragment). Doing so will make them miss important life cycle callbacks. One important callback is `onDock`, which is the perfect place to manipulate the assigned scene. Changing these two issues and also cleaning up some syntax leads to this code, which successfully makes the background transparent:

```
class MyApp : App(MyView::class)

class MyView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        button("open").action {
            find<NextRoundView>().openModal(stageStyle = StageStyle.TRANSPARENT, block = true)
        }
    }
}

class NextRoundView : View("Következő kör") {
    override val root = vbox {
        style {
            backgroundColor += Color.TRANSPARENT
            backgroundImage += URI.create("/common/rope-bg-500x300.png")
            backgroundRepeat += BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT to BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT
        }
        prefWidth = 500.0
        prefHeight = 300.0

        spacing = 20.0
        padding = insets(50, 20)
        text("A text") {
            font = Font.font(40.0)
            alignment = Pos.CENTER
        }

        button("OK") {
            font = Font.font(20.0)
            action {
                close()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        currentStage?.scene?.fill = null
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the app with the changes implemented:

[image]

Comment: Wow! This answer was greatly useful for me. Beside it solved my problem, it also taught me several other things, like using the += instead of multi() in style, calling the views correctly and where to manipulate scene. Great thanks!